# Convert List[Double] to List[String]

Tags: scala

I get a List of Double type from calling a function, I need to convert this List[Double] to List[String] for all elements. How can i do this? I tried using toString() but it fails.
My List Double :

```
List(153.0, 195.67, 212.33)
```

and when I try doing to convert it into using toString() it gives me an error as

```
type mismatch; found : List[Double] required: List[String]
```

my code looks like :

```
val apiRes = ApiResponse.fromAPI(search) //returns List of Double   
NewFormat.getVal(x.id, search,  apiPrices.toString) // Type Mismatch
```

though on REPL it looks good to me.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You need to use `List.map` and call `toString`:

```
NewFormat.getVal(x.id, search,  apiPrices.map(_.toString))
```

Calling `toString` on a `List[Double]` will yield a `String`.